# Ternary operator always returns TRUE

Tags: reactjs, typescript, conditional-operator

I have an issue with ternary operator expression.

```
AssociatedItemType.ExRatedTag ? session?.data.reloadRow(ids) : this.reloadItemRows(this.prepareItemsIdentities(ids)!),
```

AssociatedItemType is enum.

I found out that `const ? 1 : 2` always returns 1.
Why is that so? And what should I do to make my expression work as expected. I mean if true run

> session?.data.reloadRow(ids)

if not

> this.reloadItemRows(this.prepareItemsIdentities(ids)!)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try in your code `Boolean(AssociatedItemType.ExRatedTag)` if it always returns true, then the problem is in `AssociatedItemType.ExRatedTag`.

`AssociatedItemType.ExRatedTag` might return an empty object or an empty array, or the string `"false"`  and all of that are evaluated to  true in javascript

Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy  for more about what javascript considers true or false.